# How to strongly type a method in Dart?

Tags: dart

I am passing a method to another Class and storing it in a variable, how do I strongly type it?

```dart
...
  Class2(someMethod);
...
void someMethod();
```

```dart
Class2 {
  final dynamic thatMethod;
  Class2(this.thatMethod);
}
```

Checking the `runtimeType` returns `() => void`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to
https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#prefer-signatures-in-function-type-annotations

you can do `Class2(returnTypeOfFn Function(inputArgType) fn)`

eg `Class(void Function() fn)` to accept only `()=>void` functions

runnable example

```
void main() {
  acceptFunction(() => print('hi there'));
  acceptFunction((String trd) => print('this is invalid'));
  acceptFunction(()=>return "Still invalid");
}

acceptFunction(void Function() func) {
  func.call();
}
```

first line is valid